# Query call stats for each user from two different tables in one output

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT c.id_client, d.login, COUNT(*) AS calls
FROM voip.calls c, api.clients d WHERE c.id_client=d.id_client
AND c.call_start>='2013-10-28 00:00:00' AND c.call_start<'2013-11-11 00:00:00'
AND d.id_client IN 
(SELECT  e.idclient FROM voip.invoiceclients e WHERE e.clientnr='demo')
GROUP BY id_client;
```

Count *calls* for each user (id_client):

**id_client, login, calls**
369, 10315, 20
373, 10319, 3
389, 10335, 9
517, 10460, 1
519, 10462, 2
520, 10463, 2
540, 10483, 2

---

```
SELECT c.id_client, d.login, COUNT(*) AS calls_failed
FROM voip.callsfailed c, api.clients d WHERE c.id_client=d.id_client
AND c.call_start>='2013-10-28 00:00:00' AND c.call_start<'2013-11-11 00:00:00'
AND c.`IE_error_number`<>0
AND d.`id_client` IN
(SELECT  e.idclient FROM voip.invoiceclients e WHERE e.clientnr='demo')
GROUP BY id_client;
```

Count *fail calls* for each user (id_client):

**id_client, login, fail_calls**
369, 1000315, 11
373, 1000319, 2
389, 1000335, 9
458, 1000404, 1
517, 1000460, 1
519, 1000462, 1
566, 1000509, 3
591, 1000534, 13

---

How to write a query to give me the calls and failed calls in the same output:
**id_client, login, calls, fail_calls**
369, 10315, 20, 11
373, 10319, 3, 2
389, 10335, 9, 9
517, 10460, 1, 1
519, 10462, 2, 1
520, 10463, 2, 0
540, 10483, 2, 0
566, 0, 3
591, 10534, 2,13

Comment: look into JOIN syntax - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways:

1. `UNION` what you have from your existing queries and `SUM` the results:

   ```
   SELECT id_client, login, 
       SUM(calls) AS calls, SUM(calls_failed) AS calls_failed
   FROM
   (
       SELECT c.id_client, d.login, COUNT(*) AS calls, 0 AS calls_failed
       FROM voip.calls c, api.clients d WHERE c.id_client=d.id_client
       AND c.call_start>='2013-10-28 00:00:00' AND c.call_start<'2013-11-11 00:00:00'
       AND d.id_client IN 
       (SELECT  e.idclient FROM voip.invoiceclients e WHERE e.clientnr='demo')
       GROUP BY id_client
       UNION ALL
       SELECT c.id_client, d.login, 0 AS calls, COUNT(*) AS calls_failed
       FROM voip.callsfailed c, api.clients d WHERE c.id_client=d.id_client
       AND c.call_start>='2013-10-28 00:00:00' AND c.call_start<'2013-11-11 00:00:00'
       AND c.`IE_error_number`<>0
       AND d.`id_client` IN
       (SELECT  e.idclient FROM voip.invoiceclients e WHERE e.clientnr='demo')
       GROUP BY id_client
   ) x
   GROUP BY id_client, login
   ```
2. Clean up your query, pull out the common parts, and you get:

   ```
   SELECT d.id_client, d.login, 
       COALESCE(c.total, 0) AS calls, COALESCE(fc.total, 0) AS calls_failed
   FROM api.clients d
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
   (
       SELECT COUNT(*) AS total, id_client
       FROM voip.calls c
       WHERE c.call_start >= '2013-10-28 00:00:00' 
       AND c.call_start < '2013-11-11 00:00:00'
       GROUP BY id_client
   ) c ON d.id_client = c.id_client
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
   (
       SELECT COUNT(*) AS total, id_client
       FROM voip.callsfailed c
       WHERE c.call_start >= '2013-10-28 00:00:00' 
       AND c.call_start < '2013-11-11 00:00:00'
       AND c.IE_error_number <> 0
       GROUP BY id_client
   ) fc ON d.id_client = fc.id_client   
   WHERE d.id_client IN
   (
       SELECT e.idclient
       FROM voip.invoiceclients e
       WHERE e.clientnr='demo'
   )
   ```

Comment: You are very observant. I don't think I would have ever come up with this on my own. Can you give a summary of how the second option works? I have never used coalesce.

Comment: @user2924339 The `COALESCE` just substitutes 0 for any NULL values to match your desired output. Without it, you'll get NULL in the columns where there were no rows to count.